# Laravel 5.5 - Eager Loading - Remove fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to return in my endpoint the user with their roles. However when using Eager Loading I can not return only the role name array.

```
public function me()
{
     return response()->json(Auth::guard()->user()->with('roles:name')->get());
}
```

The return is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "userJohn",
        "email": "johhn@gmail.com",
        "avatar": "default.jpg",
        "created_at": "2018-01-17 15:58:16",
        "updated_at": "2018-01-17 15:58:16",
        "roles": [
            {
                "name": "free",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "role_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I need this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "userJohn",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "avatar": "default.jpg",
        "created_at": "2018-01-17 15:58:16",
        "updated_at": "2018-01-17 15:58:16",
        "roles": [ "free" ]
    }
]
```

---

UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'roles' => $user->roles->pluck('name'),
    ]);
```

But this causes the array of roles to come with the user:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "johhn",
        "email": "johhn@gmail.com",
        "avatar": "default.jpg",
        "created_at": "2018-01-17 22:17:02",
        "updated_at": "2018-01-17 22:17:02",
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "free",
                "created_at": "2018-01-17 22:10:24",
                "updated_at": "2018-01-17 22:10:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "role_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "roles": [
        "free"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the **Resource** class that comes with your Laravel **5.5** installation. Simply create a `UserResource` class like below.

Disclaimer: I just modified the sample provided in the docs, you can check the full documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class UserResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
            'roles' => $this->roles()->pluck('name'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers, you can return a json this way:

```
return new UserResource(User::find(1));
```

But if your version is 5.4 or lower, you can use **Transformers**. See the docs [here](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/). It's quite the same with laravel's resources class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Transformesr;

use App\User;
use League\Fractal;
use Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class UserTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'created_at' => $user->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $user->updated_at,
            'roles' => $user->roles()->pluck('name'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Next, inside your controllers:

```
use League\Fractal\Manager;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Item;
use League\Fractal\Serializer\DataArraySerializer;

// You may need to move this into a separate class
// then simply extend all your Transformers.
$manager = new Manager();
$manager->setSerializer(new DataArraySerializer());

return new Item(User::find(1), new UserTransformer);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Paul! Laravel 5.5 is great

Answer (score 3):

Since you're getting just one user, you can get roles with [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck):

```
auth()->user()->roles->pluck('name')
```

If you need exact structure you've shown, you could use an accessor and use it with [`$appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) property. In Laravel 5.5+ you also can use [Eloquent Resource class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) to format the data.

Comment: I update my questio, sorry for my noob doubt, but I read the documentation and it was not clear to me